# The action x could not be found for xyzController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm a beginner in Ruby on Rails and I have a problem. I'm trying to add comments to my app. Everything is working, but when I added this code to routes.rb

```
resources :galleries do
    resources :comments, module: :galleries
end
resources :articles do
    resources :comments, module: :articles
end
```

I can't update any gallery or article. My whole routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    devise_for :users


    resources :galleries do
        resources :comments, module: :galleries
    end
    resources :articles do
        resources :comments, module: :articles
    end

    match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)', via: [:post, :get]


    root 'public#index'
end
```

Comment: can you please show the error itself

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/HoJV2

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the request (articles/12?page_id=4) is falling through to the match statement and not getting picked up by your resources.  Your match statement:

```
 match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)', via: [:post, :get]
```

is matching "articles" as the controller, and looking for "12" as the action and it clearly can't find it.

I would scrap the match statement and go strictly with named routes or resourceful routing permanently, or at least while debugging.  Next, run

```
rake routes
```

and check the results.  From your routes.rb I am guessing you will have a line like this:

```
             article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)    articles#show
```

If that is indeed the case, make sure you have the show() method defined in the articles controller, and verify that the logs are showing a GET request for it.